# ensuring unique index mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to ensure an index is unique in mongodb, im using node.js however it simply does not work.

```
//ensures unique data only
db.social_media.ensureIndex( { name: 1 }, { unique: true } );

db.social_media.insert({name:'stan'}, function(err, docs){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(docs);
});

db.social_media.insert({name:'stan'}, function(err, docs){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(docs);
});
```

The following output is:

```
null
{ name: 'stan', _id: 53e9d2ee88b96dd224c6333f }
null
{ name: 'stan', _id: 53e9d2ee88b96dd224c63340 }
```

Meaning both docs where inserted - even though I specifically specified that 'name' should be unique. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting inserting documents before your index is ensured, thus creating a race condition.

Unique index can not be created if your collection contains duplicate keys.

Try the following code (but first ensure that your collection is empty, or at least contains no duplicate keys):

```
//ensures unique data only
db.social_media.ensureIndex({
  name: 1
}, {
  unique: true
}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ensureIndex failed', err);
  } else {
    db.social_media.insert({name:'stan'}, console.log);
    db.social_media.insert({name:'stan'}, console.log);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I also added 'dropDups: true' since my collection already had dups! :)